# How to set limit for zoom in core plot graph ( tell at-least 2 points visible)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I want to set the maximum zoom till at-least 2 points visible. I have added globalXRange which works good for minimum zoom out.

But i couldnt able to find solution for zoom in.

```
[plotSpace setYRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] length:[NSNumber numberWithInt:maxY+10]]];
[plotSpace setXRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] length:[NSNumber numberWithInt:maxX]]];
[plotSpace setGlobalYRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] length:[NSNumber numberWithInt:maxY+20]]];

[plotSpace setGlobalXRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] length:[NSNumber numberWithInt:maxX]]];
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:aaplPlot, nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a plot space delegate for this. Implement the `-plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:` method and return the desired plot range. Use the plot range parameter value if it meets your requirements or the min/max range value if the parameter value is outside your desired visible range.